# Normalizing matched data in R

Tags: r, normalize

Consider:

```
Pair       X  
 1         2 
 1         3
 2         1
 2         2
```

If I have a dataframe that is structured like the example above, how do I normalize column X given the *Pair* column?

In other words, the two elements should be translated to 0.4 (2/(2+3)) and 0.6 (3/(2+3)) for Pair 1 and .333 (1/(1+2)) and .666 (2/(1+2)) for Pair 2.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a work order, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R:

```
df$norm <- with(df, X/ave(X, Pair, FUN = sum))
df
#  Pair X norm
#1    1 2 0.40
#2    1 3 0.60
#3    2 1 0.33
#4    2 2 0.67
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Pair) %>% mutate(norm = X/sum(X))
```

and `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, norm := X/sum(X), Pair]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Pair = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), X = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
df$norm <- with(df, X/rowsum(X, Pair)[Pair])
df$norm
#[1] 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Pair = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), X = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```